# mysql insert turns ★ into â˜…

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

When I do an insert from my application all ★ (stars) turns into "â˜…"

How can I stop this from happening?

*It works if I directly insert it through phpmyadmin, but not when doing it using this php:

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$inputTime = mysql_escape_string($_POST['inputTime']);
$inputBotid = mysql_escape_string($_POST['inputBotid']);
$inputImage = mysql_escape_string($_POST['inputImage']);
$inputName = mysql_escape_string($_POST['inputSkin']);
$inputStatus = mysql_escape_string($_POST['inputStatus']);
$inputTradeid = mysql_escape_string($_POST['inputTradeid']);

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO items (trade, market_hash_name, status, img, botid, time)
VALUES ('$inputTime', '$inputName', '$inputStatus', '$inputImage', '$inputBotid','$inputTime')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Check the database's collation and how you insert the data. And read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Mojibake.  Search [*this Q&A*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for 'Mojibake' to see what causes and how to prevent it.

Since you are into symbols, you might want to use `utf8mb4`, not just `utf8` in MySQL.  The former includes various 4-byte Emoji.

Also, see [*PHP tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#php).  The most important is `$mysqli_obj->set_charset('utf8mb4');` right after connecting.